# Change the NegativeButton's text in an AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have subclassed `AlertDialog.Builder` to create my own customised dialog. In that dialog I added a `CheckBox`. What I want is to change the text of the `NegativeButton` from `Cancel` to something else, when the `CheckBox` is checked:

```
myCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {           
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // change text of negative button
        }
    }
});
```

How should I do that?

I have tried to get a reference to the button using

```
Button btnNegative = (Button)dlgView.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

but that returns `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

`Calling findViewById() will search for views within your Activity's layout and not your dialog's view. You need to call findViewById() on the specific View that you set as your dialog's layout.`

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null);
searchDialog.setView(dialogView);
EditText tagText = (EdiText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tagField); 
searchDialog.setPositiveButton( ... ) ...
AlertDialog myAlert = searchDialog.create(); //returns an AlertDialog from a Builder.
myAlert.show();
```

Try this may be useful  read from a blog , may be useful

`AlertDialog dialog = your_builder.create();`

`Button b = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);`

Comment: I know and I do use that for all other widgets. But as I subclass the whole thing, I can also make use of `setPositiveButton` and have it rendered in the correct style. I use the negative and positive buttons and I don't want to create an entire layout, just to be able to change a text.

Comment: i just updated a line at last try that , maybe helpful

Comment: Almost. I want that `Button` in my `AlertDialog.Builder` class, not in my activity.

Comment: Accept because of the `getButton` that lead me to my solution. I provided the end solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an instance of the created `AlertDialog`, and use its buttons like this:

```
class MyBuilder extends AlertDialog.Builder {
    AlertDialog myDialog;

    @Override
    public AlertDialog show() {
        myDialog = super.show();

        return myDialog;
    }

    public MyBuilder(Activity act) {
        CheckBox cb = ... ;
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Button btnNegative = myDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```